# std::ifstream crashes in release build on Windows with exit code 0xC0000409: Unknown software exception

Tags: c++, windows, segmentation-fault, release, ifstream

I'm reading a file using `std::ifstream`:

```
printf("Before stream initialization\n");
ifstream stream(file_path, ios::binary);
printf("Stream initialized\n");
ifstream::pos_type position = stream.tellg();
auto file_size = position;
printf("Position acquired\n");
```

However, the program crashes in the release mode of the binary. Here is the compiled assembly code snippet:

```
.text:0000000000413411                 lea     rcx, aBeforeStreamIn ; "Before stream initialization\n"
.text:0000000000413418                 mov     rbx, rax
.text:000000000041341B                 call    _ZL6printfPKcz  ; printf(char const*,...)
.text:000000000041341B ;   } // starts at 41340C
.text:0000000000413420                 lea     rdi, [rsp+878h+var_248]
.text:0000000000413428                 lea     rcx, [rdi+0D8h] ; this
.text:000000000041342F                 mov     [rsp+878h+var_820], rdi
.text:0000000000413434                 call    _ZNSt8ios_baseC1Ev ; std::ios_base::ios_base(void)
.text:0000000000413439                 xor     r8d, r8d
.text:000000000041343C                 mov     rax, cs:_refptr__ZTVSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE
.text:0000000000413443                 xor     edx, edx
.text:0000000000413445                 mov     [rsp+878h+var_90], r8w
.text:000000000041344E                 pxor    xmm0, xmm0
.text:0000000000413452                 movaps  [rsp+878h+var_88], xmm0
.text:000000000041345A                 movaps  [rsp+878h+var_78], xmm0
.text:0000000000413462                 mov     [rsp+878h+var_98], 0
.text:000000000041346E                 add     rax, 10h
.text:0000000000413472                 mov     [rsp+878h+var_170], rax
.text:000000000041347A                 mov     rax, cs:_refptr__ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE
.text:0000000000413481                 mov     rsi, [rax+8]
.text:0000000000413485                 mov     rcx, [rax+10h]
.text:0000000000413489                 mov     rax, [rsi-18h]
.text:000000000041348D                 mov     [rsp+878h+var_248], rsi
.text:0000000000413495                 mov     [rsp+878h+var_7E8], rcx
.text:000000000041349D                 mov     [rsp+878h+var_7F0], rsi
.text:00000000004134A5                 mov     [rsp+rax+878h+var_248], rcx
.text:00000000004134AD                 mov     [rsp+878h+var_240], 0
.text:00000000004134B9                 mov     rcx, [rsi-18h]
.text:00000000004134BD                 add     rcx, rdi
.text:00000000004134C0 ;   try {
.text:00000000004134C0                 call    _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4initEPSt15basic_streambufIcS1_E ; std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>>::init(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)
.text:00000000004134C0 ;   } // starts at 4134C0
.text:00000000004134C5                 mov     rax, cs:_refptr__ZTVSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE
.text:00000000004134CC                 lea     rcx, [rdi+10h]
.text:00000000004134D0                 add     rax, 18h
.text:00000000004134D4                 mov     [rsp+878h+var_248], rax
.text:00000000004134DC                 mov     rax, cs:_refptr__ZTVSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE
.text:00000000004134E3                 add     rax, 40h
.text:00000000004134E7                 mov     [rsp+878h+var_170], rax
.text:00000000004134EF ;   try {
.text:00000000004134EF                 call    _ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEEC1Ev ; std::basic_filebuf<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_filebuf(void)
.text:00000000004134EF ;   } // starts at 4134EF
.text:00000000004134F4                 lea     rdx, [rdi+10h]
.text:00000000004134F8                 lea     rcx, [rdi+0D8h]
.text:00000000004134FF ;   try {
.text:00000000004134FF                 call    _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4initEPSt15basic_streambufIcS1_E ; std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>>::init(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)
.text:0000000000413504                 lea     rcx, [rdi+10h]
.text:0000000000413508                 mov     r8d, 0Eh
.text:000000000041350E                 mov     rdx, rbx
.text:0000000000413511                 call    _ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4openEPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode ; std::basic_filebuf<char,std::char_traits<char>>::open(char const*,std::_Ios_Openmode)
.text:0000000000413516                 mov     rdx, [rsp+878h+var_248]
.text:000000000041351E                 add     rdi, [rdx-18h]
.text:0000000000413522                 test    rax, rax
.text:0000000000413525                 mov     rcx, rdi
.text:0000000000413528                 jz      loc_414688
.text:000000000041352E                 xor     edx, edx
.text:0000000000413530                 call    _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5clearESt12_Ios_Iostate ; std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>>::clear(std::_Ios_Iostate)
.text:0000000000413530 ;   } // starts at 4134FF
.text:0000000000413535
.text:0000000000413535 loc_413535:                             ; CODE XREF: PointerSearcher::parse_pointer_map(void)+1363↓j
.text:0000000000413535                 lea     rcx, aStreamInitiali ; "Stream initialized\n"
.text:000000000041353C ;   try {
.text:000000000041353C                 call    _ZL6printfPKcz  ; printf(char const*,...)
```

In my function it crashes at this line:

```
.text:0000000000413504                 lea     rcx, [rdi+10h]
```

The output is:

```
Before stream initialization

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000409)
```

The stacktrace is:

```
std::locale::operator=(std::locale const&)
std::ios_base::_M_init()
std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::init(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)
MyExecutable::myFunction()
```

The crash only happens in the `Windows` binary. The binary works in release mode for `Linux`. I'm using the `MinGW` compiler to compile the Windows binary and the compilation flags are:

```
-fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG
```

They're the default `CMake` release build flags. I also made sure the passed `file_path` is correct.

`gdb` says:

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004a2521 in std::locale::operator=(std::locale const&) ()

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004a2521 in std::locale::operator=(std::locale const&) ()
[Thread 48616.0xc508 exited with code 3221225477]
[Thread 48616.0xc510 exited with code 3221225477]
[Thread 48616.0xc638 exited with code 3221225477]
[Inferior 1 (process 48616) exited with code 030000000005]
```

The compiler version:

```
"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe" --version
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Does anyone have an idea what went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Post the smallest code you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem. Posting snippets that you think might be the source of the problem is rarely productive.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I can't do that. When I place the file reading code snippet in `main()` it works normally. But in my code it causes an exit code of `0xC0000005 (Access Violation)` instead of executing the `std::ifstream` constructor successfully...

Comment: It's probably not the stream at all, but what you're doing elsewhere (most likely trashing the heap or the stack).  That is why @PeteBecker is saying you need to post more code.

Comment: Since tho code works fine in isolation, the problem is probably somewhere else. This kind of thing usually is the result of a stray pointer that hasn’t been properly initialized or a write outside the bounds of an array. Those can be nasty to track down.

Comment: The crash is not at the `lea ecx, [edi+10h]`. That's the return address on the stack, which is nowhere near the actual crash point.

Comment: I compared all variables from the `Linux` binary as well as the `Windows` one during execution. No memory corruption occurred. Even just calling the `ifstream` constructor causes the `ACCESS_VIOLATION` `0xC0000005` error code crash: `std::ifstream stream;` This should rule out quite a lot. Any ideas?

Comment: The corruption isn't in your variables. It's in the variables internal to the system (like the ones that keep track of which memory on the heap is being used for what). You could try using a heap verifier tool, like valgrind or pageheap.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I found some minor memory leaks using `valgrind` and fixed them. Now `valgrind` is happy. This didn't help solve the problem in this question though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be a [`MinGW`](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) compiler bug since when using `MSVC` in `Visual Studio` to compile the code, the same exception does not occur either.

Comment: More likely you have a bug in the code , that happens to not cause an exception in MSVC for now. But even if you do think it is a bug in g++ for windows, it would be helpful to others to try and make a MCVE so that the bug can be addressed

Comment: @M.M:
It's not a bug in my code if calling the `ifstream` constructor blank without any argments causes an exception. There is nothing wrong. 2 compilers say it's fine and 1 crashes the binary at this point (and always!). Also I debugged and inspected all variables and there is no corruption. There you go. Making an `MCVE` is troublesome since the bug can't be replicated that easily.

Comment: If you can't replicate the bug then you have no basis for claiming it to be a compiler bug . "I haven't found any bug in my code" does not mean there is no bug in your code.

Comment: That may be true but using `MSVC` for `Windows` is generally better than `MinGW` and I never ran into those always occurring crashing problems in regards to the `ifstream` anymore so I stopped caring about replicating this bug in an `MCVE`. The `MinGW` toolchain I used is a special distribution so it's high likely it may be the sole reason for the bug but we may never know after all. As long as everything works on `Windows` and `Linux` with at least one compiler it's all good. :)