# Segmentation fault when compiling with mingw g++ 7.2, declaring an ifstream and using extern "C"

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mingw, ifstream, extern-c

I'm was writing some interfacing code to call c++ routines from fortran which is why I dumped the methods into an extern "C" block. When compiling with g++.exe (x86_64-win32-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.2.0 under Windows 10 I was getting segmentation faults when declaring an ifstream object. I broke it down to the following code snippet:

**tester.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>

void x(){
    std::ifstream infile;
}

extern "C"
{
    void whatever() {
    }
}

int main(){
    x();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm building with following commmand: **g++ tester.cpp -o tester.out -O3**. The program runs without faults when building with -O0 but crashes for -O1,-O2 and -O3. Compiling using msvc under Windows and g++  8.30 under Linux produces no segmentation fault. Both the extern "C" block and the call to x() are required for the program to crash.

Running gdb backtrace gives the following output:

```
    Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000006fce18b2 in ?? ()
   from C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x000000006fce18b2 in ?? ()
   from C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#1  0x000000006fcf7b6c in ?? ()
   from C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#2  0x000000006fcf9b41 in ?? ()
   from C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#3  0x000000000040163a in std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream (this=0x61fc20, __in_chrg=<optimized out>,
    __vtt_parm=<optimized out>)
    at C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/fstream:482
#4  x () at tester.cpp:4
#5  0x0000000000402ede in main () at tester.cpp:14
```

Is this a bug with mingw or am I missing something. [std::ifstream crashes in release build on Windows with exit code 0xC0000409: Unknown software exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421495/stdifstream-crashes-in-release-build-on-windows-with-exit-code-0xc0000409-unk) might be related.

Comment: The stack trace doesn't correspond to the posted code...

Comment: You are right, sorry. I updated the trace

Comment: You need to make sure your code is loading the libstdc++ that comes with your compiler not some random version picked up from the path from your git installation

Comment: I doubt this is a compiler bug.  If a compiler couldn't produce a correct executable from such a toy program, that would be rather unfortunate.  As mentioned, probably an invalid / incompatible library is being used.

Comment: Thanks Alan! That was the issue. Replacing C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll with the one in C:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib makes the segfault go away.

Comment: Hmm, replacing that library will presumably just make git crash instead, fixing your path environment variable is probably a better approach