# Why do I receive a segmentation fault on opening a file with path received as a parameter with -O3 optimization in C++

Tags: c++

I have a main function which calls a function `func`, with a valid file path as a parameter. I use `std::ifstream` to open the file. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int func(std::string filepath)
{
    std::ifstream file(filepath);
    file.close();
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::string filepath = "file.txt";
    func(filepath);
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling the program with `-O3` flag enabled and running it, I receive signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. I use MinGW gcc version 9.2.0

```
g++ main.cpp -O3
./a
```

Here's the stack trace I get from gdb

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x6fc03a47 in ?? () from C:\Program Files\Git\mingw32\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#1  0x6fc1b4b2 in ?? () from C:\Program Files\Git\mingw32\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#2  0x6fc1cb60 in ?? () from C:\Program Files\Git\mingw32\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#3  0x004014c7 in basic_ifstream (__mode=std::_S_in, __s=..., this=0x22fdd4,
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>, __vtt_parm=<optimized out>)
    at c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/istream:606
#4  _fu4___ZTVSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE () at main.cpp:7
#5  0x00404317 in main ()
    at c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:300
#6  0x00401233 in ?? ()
#7  0x004012e5 in mainCRTStartup ()
```

But it works fine if I compile it with `-O3` flag disabled

It also works fine, If open the file from the main function itself

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::string filepath = "file.txt";
    std::ifstream file(filepath);
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works fine even with `-O3` flag enabled

How can I make the first program work with `-O3` flag enabled?

Comment: you get a SIGSEGV when you run the executable or when you compile the code? If it is really the latter then its a bug in your compiler

Comment: The compiling process works fine. The problem is with the executable

Comment: Can you please add `-g` as a compiler flag and allow core dumps? `ulimit -c unlimited`. Can you then please add the stack trace `gdb a.out core` and `bt`?

Comment: BTW: which compiler version are you using `gcc --version`?

Comment: Just for the record: Your programs are both fine and should not cause any issue, regardless of optimizations. The question is rather what in your environment (compiler, OS etc) is causing this. Running the code in a debugger or `strace` could help track down the issue. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask] if you haven't already.

Comment: `g++` without `-o` creates `a.out`, that is just a typo right? Otherwise you are running different executable

Comment: @Quimby No, it's on Windows; GCC produces `a.exe` instead of `a.out`. `./a` is not a typo.

Comment: You seem to be mixing two installations of of MinGW: one at `c:/mingw/` and one at `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw32`. If correctly setup the `libstdc++-6.dll` from the former directory should be linked, not the latter. What is the full path of `g++`?

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601469/segmentation-fault-when-compiling-with-mingw-g-7-2-declaring-an-ifstream-and

Comment: @j6t Oh, ok thanks.

Comment: @user17732522 C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe

Comment: @user17732522 is right. I replaced `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw32/bin/libstdc++-6.dll` with `C:/MinGW/bin/libstdc++-6.dll` and it works fine now. And so far, there is no issues with my git installations. But is it a good solution to replace link libraries? Is there a better solution?

Comment: @MartinHill No, as mentioned in the other question's comments, it is a bad idea to just replace the DLLs. The other version is going to be there for a reason. I don't know enough about Windows/MinGW to understand why the wrong DLL is loaded.